# Get notifications for how I lost reputation

Tags: support, reputation

I recently lost some reputation points (about 30. I know it shows 20 but during the same period I got an answer upvoted as well.) I do not know how but it may be because of a removed upvote, deselecting as the correct answer or or some bug. I do not care much about the points all I want is to `get notifications for how I lost those points`. Is that possible?

@Jokerdino - I couldn't find anything. neither on https://askubuntu.com/reputation or the link which jrg provided. But anyways forget about these rep points, my main aim is to get notifications in the future for how I lost these points.

[image]
I had got the same notification for the main site as well

Comment: Do you see any records in your reputation page? Look as far as the record allows you and figure out why you probably lost the rep. Or at least when it happened. Exact date would be very much recommended.

Comment: edited my question

Answer (score 1):

Well, you were deleting answers. ;)

Take a look at your reputation tab:

https://askubuntu.com/users/29470/ashu?tab=reputation

And it will show (to you, and nobody else) what posts lost you reputation.

Comment: actually i had lost the rep a few days ago(like a week ago) was feeling too lazy to ask about it. the posts deletion happened today.  But according to your post if i have some upvotes on a post and i delete it i lose those reps also?? isnt that wrong?

Comment: @Ashu If you have upvotes on a post and you delete it, you will ofcourse lose the rep. Doesn't it make sense to you?

Comment: i mean that say i post a answer that is completely off topic and i get 10 downvotes ie 20 rep gone . then i delete that post and i get back the points? the ill do that on every question. i can even misuse it to post links to a blog or a video & then delete it after getting some downvotes

Comment: @Ashu The system has very complicated and accurate systems that let moderators sniff out abuse like that. Please, don't try it, but you are correct.

Comment: anyways that is not my point.. i have edited the question plzz see it