# Bug in writing titles

Tags: support, asking-questions

Referring to my [previous question](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/3099/lost-reputation), I typed the title as `Lost REPUTATION !` but I got `Lost REPUTATION?` Is this a bug? Or some secret feature?

Answer (score 3):

This isn't a bug, it's a feature. Typically questions aren't statements, but questions. So Stack Exchange [lightly nudges you to the correct punctuation.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/115327/stop-rewriting-trailing-exclamation-marks-as-question-marks)

Comment: The fourth point in the answer is `Spaces before trailing punctuation removed`... in my case they are not only removing the space but also the exclaimation mark. So the problem isnt actually solved as stated by the answer.

Comment: Right, the answer states that Stack Exchange will remove excessive punctuation (like the `!`) and replace it with a `?`. In addition they will also remove the space between the last word and the punctuation mark.

Comment: so in the end what can be done?

Comment: Instead of trying to force the software to accept a variation of the less-informative "Lost REPUTATION !", use the better "Why did I lose reputation?" or "How can I see how I lost reputation?" as a title to your question.

Comment: good point. ill make the change.